background-image in diagonal pattern
When using background: url("/images/bg.png") repeat; the images display directly next to each other. Given that the image in question is rhombus how to make it so the images are positioned with a 45 degree offset each time in order to form a diagonal pattern?
Image:

Desirable outcome: 

There is a repeating pattern there. Can you see it?

You have to use the image twice. 60px and 39px are half the width and height of the original image


html {
  --img: url(https://i.sstatic.net/H3hst2XO.png);
  background: var(--img), var(--img) 60px 39px;
}



